# What is equivalent of SAS (shared access signature) feature of Azure Storage on S3?

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, azure-storage

Azure provides shared access signatures ([[1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee395415.aspx)], [[2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn140255.aspx)], [[3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn140256.aspx)]) that can delegate access (read/write) to specific blobs/containers/tables/queues in an Azure Storage account using an access key generated through the REST API. Does AWS offer a similar feature?

Comment: You can either use S3 bucket policies or IAM policies.

Answer (score 8):

Presigned URL in S3 is the equivalent: 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html

There are also ways to generate them with SDKs not mentioned in this documentation, you can google it.

Python for example:
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-presigned-urls.html

Answer (score 3):

Equivalent for shared access signature in Amazon AWS is [`Query String Authentication`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/S3_QSAuth.html) however it is only for Amazon S3 (equivalent to Windows Azure Blob Storage). AWS does not have anything similar to shared access signature for SimpleDB/DynamoDB (counterpart of Windows Azure Table Storage) and Simple Queue Service (counterpart of Windows Azure Queue Service).

I also did a comparison between Amazon AWS and Windows Azure Storage Services (S3 v/s Blob Storage etc.) in a series of blog posts which you can read here: http://gauravmantri.com/?s=Amazon+Comparing. Thought you might find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

It is almost identical to what Azure provides, just without a special name like SAS.  See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html for details.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it yet but looks like pre-signed URLs are the thing: See the "Amazon S3: Getting a pre-signed URL for a PUT operation with a specific payload" section of http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/node-examples.html